# Keras LSTM go_backwards usage

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, deep-learning, keras

I have a question regarding the usage of the go_backwards argument in the Keras LSTM model layer.  The documentation for this layer can be found here:  https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#lstm.

Question1:  If I set the "go_backwards" flag to True, do I still feed the input data "forwards" during the training process.  For example, if an input sentence in English normally reads "I fell", and it's German translation reads "Ich fiel", would I feed it forwards ("I fell", "Ich fiel"), or backwards ("fell I", "fiel Ich") during the training process.

Question 2: Same question for making model predictions, is the data fed forward ("I fell"), or reverse ("fell I")?

Question 3: If I was trying to use the model below and wanted to reverse the corpus data, would I set the go_backwards flag to true in both LSTM layers or just one?

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(src_vocab, embedding_dim, input_length=source_steps, mask_zero=True))
model.add(LSTM(embedding_dim,go_backwards=True))
model.add(RepeatVector(target_steps))
model.add(LSTM(embedding_dim, return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(tar_vocab, activation='softmax')))
# compile model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
# summarize defined model
model.summary()
```

I think I should feed all data forward but I can't find any documentation that convinces me that this is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`go_backwards` just reverses whatever sequence that you give to the LSTM. The [code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/e24625095a33a5c9a2d016018203938e9bb2ccbf/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L2680) is pretty clear to understand.

```
if go_backwards: 
    inputs = reverse(inputs, 0)
```

> Question1: If I set the "go_backwards" flag to True, do I still feed
>   the input data "forwards" during the training process. For example, if
>   an input sentence in English normally reads "I fell", and it's German
>   translation reads "Ich fiel", would I feed it forwards ("I fell", "Ich
>   fiel"), or backwards ("fell I", "fiel Ich") during the training
>   process.

Yes you feed the data in the sequence that it occurs(forwards) and `go_backwards` just reverses it.

> Question 2: Same question for making model predictions, is the data
>   fed forward ("I fell"), or reverse ("fell I")?

The same thing happens during inference time.

> Question 3: If I was trying to use the model below and wanted to
>   reverse the corpus data, would I set the go_backwards flag to true in
>   both LSTM layers or just one?

Not sure why you would want to reverse the input for the decoder(second) LSTM. In the [original seq2seq paper](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/5346-sequence-to-sequence-learning-with-neural-networks.pdf?utm_campaign=DonanimHaber&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=DonanimHaber), if I remember correctly, only the inputs are reversed and not the targets. So I would recommend to just apply `go_backwards` to the first LSTM.

P.S: I would suggest going through the seq2seq tutorial/example from the official Keras [blog](https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html) rather than whatever code that you are trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

I guess Q1 and Q2 is answered well and I agree with @scarecrow.

Re Q3, the reason for reversing the encoder sequence is **very much dependent** on the problem you're solving (discuss this in detail later). The idea is that, it helps to build a **strong communication** between the encoder and decoder, helping the decoder to decode more effectively. For example, say you want to translate `A B C` to `alpha beta gamma delta`. By reversing the source sequence the task becomes,

`C B A -> alpha beta gamma delta`

And if `A` is strongly related to `alpha` this gives a very good starting point for the decoder. And yes, it creates more distance between the last words in each sequence.

But when you're getting to the end of decoding, you can compensate by relying more on what you decoded so far to give a good next prediction as well. For example, in a translation task, if have decoded `I snore in my ______`, you can pretty well solve this without the corresponding source word. **Note**: This discussion about predicting the words at the end, is my opinion.

But also beware that this can hurt than helping in some occasions. Think about a situation where source language is `subject-verb-object` and target language is `object-subject-verb`. Reversing the source will give `object-verb-subject` which makes the starting word of the decoder far away from the source's corresponding word.

Answer (score 0):

Another benefit of reversing the input is as follows:

Since RNN needs same length for all sequences in a batch of training data, padding tokens are used at the end of the shorter sentences so that all sentences/sequences in a batch are of same length. So towards the end of encoder, most tokens will be padding tokens and thus creating a long distance between the decoder output and encoder input:

For example, say the sequence length is set as 10.

Q: Where are you going?

A: I am going to the playground.

Encoder input: Where are you going ? PAD_token PAD_token PAD_token PAD_token PAD_token

Decoder Output: I am going to the playground EOS_token

There are 5 not-useful padding tokens between last word of encoder input and first word of decoder output.

Reversed encoder input: PAD_token PAD_token PAD_token PAD_token PAD_token  ? going you are Where

Decoder Output: I am going to the playground EOS_token

Now, the distance between actual encoder input and decoder output is less!

After attention was introduced in seq-to-seq architecture, the attention values take care of this problem and reversing of inputs is not necessary (Note: last sentence is  just my observation).Encoder maps the source sequence to the hidden vector which is the last encoder state - and this context/thought vector is input to decoder states [other than the previous decoder state and the previous word in the target/output sequence] when attention is not used.